# .DS_Store in Android project

Tags: android, apk

As I develop Android apps, I switch between Windows and OS X (on the same app) such that the `.DS_Store` file created by OS X appears in Windows. For Git, I can add `.DS_Store` to the ignore file, so no problem there. But, does `.DS_Store` make it into apk file (and hence increase the size of the apk file)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it's just a thing from Mac OS. You should just add it to .gitignore.

Comment: I understand it is from OS X and the I can add it to .gitgnore, but, unless I misunderstand, this has nothing to do with whether it is included in the apk or not.

Comment: APK file is made from dex files, resources and manifest,i.e. nothing else doesn't get into apk. There are rules for building apk, files which are not included into that rules are ignored.

Comment: This link: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html explains the building of an apk file. There is "other resources" which is not definitively defined.